# Two sum but sum is in a range

Tags: c++, algorithm

How this can be solved faster than O(N^2) without using Binary indexed tree (O(NlogN), but Memory Out Limit)

```
arr = [6, 2, 3, 5, 1, 6], l = 5, h = 7
```

Find number of pairs i, j such that `i < j && (arr[i] + arr[j] >= l && arr[i] + arr[j] <= r)`

O(N^2) solution is very straight-forward, but TLE.

What I tried:

1. Using Binary Indexed Tree, but get Memory Limit Exceeded.

Anyone has ideas?

Comment: Are you learning C++ or just doing some competitve coding for fun?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort the array in ascending order and, for each i, binary search (in `(i , n]`) the first `j` for which the first condition is true. Let it be `j1`. Then, binary search (again in `(i, n]`) the last j for which the second condition is true. Let it be `j2`. If everything is ok,  add `|j2 - j1 + 1|` to the answer.

The overall time complexity is `O(n * log n)` and the memory complexity is `O(n)`.

Comment: Oh, I got it, I pay too much attention on the order of the pair of elements. For your solution, we need to divide the final result by 2, since we double count each pair, right?

Comment: @LGDGODV there is no need to divide by 2. I edited my answer to explain. You only binary search ahead of the element you are currently looking at in the sorted array

Comment: @LGDGODV yes, the trick in this problem is to notice that the order of the elements doesn't alter the final answer.